# Android Paginação fixa

Tags: android, paginação

Tenho uma `gridView` que estou populando através de um `WebService`. O problema começa quando quero disparar um evento digamos que `clico` ao deslizar a tela para esquerda ou para direita sei que existe o `pageview`, mas não quero mudar de tela quero apenas que o usuário tenha sensação de mudança ou seja que os dados sejam carregados após o gesto mas não pagine para uma próxima tela.

Sendo mais claro como um calendário onde a `grid` permanece a mesma mas muda apenas os valores. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi o cenário, você tem um GridView que representa os dias de um mês (um calendário). E quer que de alguma forma alterar os elementos desse GridView ao realizar uma determinada ação. Correto?

Comment: Exato ao deslizar para esquerda ou para direita disparar um evento(método que tenho para popular a grid) ao mover para direita aumento 1 mês para esquerda diminui 1 mês.

Comment: Tem como atribuir esse evento para um gridview, pois consegui criar mas o evento só dispara fora da gridview e nao em cima dela.

Comment: Na verdade, o `GridView` "absorve" o evento porque ele é "scrollavel" e tem o tratamento de `click` e `longclick` nos itens. Você teria que criar o seu próprio `GridView` sobreescrevendo o método `onTouchEvent` e talvez o método `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Detectar se houve movimentação horizontal, fazer sua ação e não deixar a ação do `GridView` padrão rodar. Caso não seja horizontal você precisa deixar o tratamento padrão rodar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser que isso funcione para você. Pode utilizar o metodo **onTouchEvent** em sua activity como o exemplo retirado do site [developer android](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

switch(action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                "of current screen element");
        return true;      
    default : 
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

Comment: Acho que vale a pena acrescentar que junto com essa solução, para descobrir a velocidade/direção do movimento vale a pena olhar este tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html